# How to determine if we are in a child process in apache?

Tags: apache, apache2.2, apr

On Windows **AP_PARENT_PID** environment variable is set for every child process Apache creates.

I am looking for similar thing in Linux which can be used to check if the current process is child or parent.

P.S. I am using Apache 2.2

Comment: Take a look here maybe: http://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line